# How to use python subprocess.run for calling other python files and bash files

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, pytest, wsl-2

I am using python subprocess.run to call a .sh file and .py file that are located in another directory distant from the source. This is the only connection between the two directories making importing not practical. The code below has been simplified to the bare minimum.

```
parent-dir/
├── dirA
│   ├── main.py
│   └── main_test.py
└── dirB
    ├── app.sh
    └── utility.py
```

main.py

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Tuple, Optional
import subprocess
import sys

dir_a_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    
# get the parent folder
parent_dir = dir_a_path.parent
dir_b_path = str(parent_dir.joinpath("dirB"))


def execute_bash_command(command: str, cwd: Optional[str]=None) -> Tuple[int, str, str]:
    """Runs a bash command in a new shell
    exit_code, stdout, stderr = execute_bash_command(command)

    Args:
        command (str): the command to run
        cwd (Optional[str]): where to run the command line from. 
            Use this instead of 'cd some_dir/ && command'

    Raises:
        Exception: Exception

    Returns:
        Tuple[int, str, str]: [exit code, stdout, stderr]
    """
    try:
        print(f"Executing {command} from cwd: {cwd}")
        output = subprocess.run(command, cwd=cwd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, check=True, shell=True)
        stdout = output.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip()
        print(stdout)
        return (output.returncode, stdout, "")
    
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
        print(f"error: {cpe}")
        stdout = cpe.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip()
        stderr = cpe.stderr.decode("utf-8").strip()
        return (cpe.returncode, stdout, stderr)

def call_app() -> Tuple[int, str, str]:
    command = [
        "./app.sh",
        "install"
    ]
    command = " ".join(command)
    return execute_bash_command(command=command, cwd=dir_b_path)

def call_utility() -> Tuple[int, str, str]:
    command = [
        sys.executable,
        "greet"
    ]
    command = " ".join(command)
    return execute_bash_command(command=command, cwd=dir_b_path)
```

main_test.py

```
from main import call_app, call_utility

def test_call_app():
    code, stdout, stderr = call_app()
    assert code == 0
    assert stdout == "Installing application..."
    
def test_call_utility():
    code, stdout, stderr = call_utility()
    assert code == 0
    assert stdout == "running command greet"

def test_execute_bash_command():
    """ Creates dummy file """
    exit_code, stdout, _ = execute_bash_command("touch tmp/test.txt")
    assert exit_code == 0
```

app.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "greet"]; then
    echo "Hello, world!"
elif [ "$1" = "install"]; then
    echo "Installing application..."
else
    echo "Usage: $0 {greet|install}"
    exit 1
fi
```

utility.py

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"running command {sys.argv[1]}")
```

When I run from the terminal `python utility.py greet` or `./app.sh install`, it runs fine. The issue is when I execute `main_test.py` using `python -m pytest`. I get errors that the subprocess exited with different codes.

Errors:

```
Executing ./app.sh install from cwd: /mnt/c/Users/XXX/source/python-testing/parent-dir/dirB
error: Command './app.sh install' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

or

```
Executing /usr/bin/python3 greet from cwd: /mnt/c/Users/XXX/source/python-testing/parent-dir/dirB
error: Command '/usr/bin/python3 greet' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

These errors are exist while running pytest from both powershell and WSL2.

These errors are mimic the actual errors running on the codebase.

Why is this not working as intended? Is using `cwd` in the `subprocess.run` not the right way to go? I'm stuck because I'm trying to refactor some nasty code that magically works, but is not clear, so I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I have several comments:

- About `subprocess.run`

  - The command should be a list of strings. My experience leads me to believe that a list of string is less troublesome than a single string. The function `run` will split the string any way.
  - Not to use `shell=True` because it leads to unexpected behaviors and the source of security vulnerability
  - I do not put in `check=True`. That way, the return code is capture, and stderr is filled. I don't have to put my call into a try/except block
  - I like the `text=True` option because then, what I got back for stdout and stderr are text, not bytes
  - I like the `capture_output=True` option, instead of using stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE. It is much more convenient, clean, and clearer
  - Instead of returning the return code, stdout, stdin, I just return the whole [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object and let the caller have fun with it.
- About the tests

  - I added trailing newlines to the output
  - I changed `test_execute_bash_command` a little because the `touch` command will always failed
  - I rename `main_test.py` to `test_main.py` because `pytest` looks for `test_*.py` by default

That being said, here is main.py:

```py
import logging
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
DIR_B_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.parent / "dirB"


def execute_bash_command(
    command: list, cwd: Optional[Path] = None
) -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
    logging.debug("Executing command %r from dir: %r", command, cwd)
    completed_process = subprocess.run(
        command,
        cwd=cwd,
        capture_output=True,
        text=True,
    )
    return completed_process


def call_app() -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
    command = ["./app.sh", "install"]
    return execute_bash_command(command=command, cwd=DIR_B_PATH)


def call_utility() -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
    command = [sys.executable, "utility.py", "greet"]
    return execute_bash_command(command, cwd=DIR_B_PATH)
```

And here is test_main.py:

```py
from main import call_app, call_utility, execute_bash_command


def test_call_app():
    completed_process = call_app()
    assert completed_process.returncode == 0
    assert completed_process.stdout == "Installing application...\n"


def test_call_utility():
    completed_process = call_utility()
    assert completed_process.returncode == 0
    assert completed_process.stdout == "running command greet\n"


def test_execute_bash_command():
    """Creates dummy file"""
    completed_process = execute_bash_command(["ls"])
    assert completed_process.returncode == 0
```

Tests result:

```
dirA/test_main.py::test_call_app PASSED
dirA/test_main.py::test_call_utility PASSED
dirA/test_main.py::test_execute_bash_command PASSED
```

#### Update

After reviewing my own implementation on `execute_bash_command`, I realize it is just a shell over `subprocess.run`. That means, I can  further simplify it. Here is version 2 of main.py:

```py
import functools
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path

DIR_B_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.parent / "dirB"


execute_bash_command = functools.partial(
    subprocess.run,
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
)


def call_app() -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
    command = ["./app.sh", "install"]
    return execute_bash_command(command, cwd=DIR_B_PATH)


def call_utility() -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
    command = [sys.executable, "utility.py", "greet"]
    return execute_bash_command(command, cwd=DIR_B_PATH)
```

By using `functools.partial`, I am saying that `execute_bash_command` is the same as `subprocess.run`, but with a few default parameters; specifically `text=True` and `capture_output=True`.